# 3d cube rotation backwards text in div

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a 3d cube rotation, that happens on hover.  Everything works fine except one thing.  When you roll over and the cube rotates showing a new side with text....the text is backwards, not sure why this is happening.  I have a JS fiddle set up, and any help I can get on this would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3ewZ/6/

html:

This is back

```
<div class='box-scene col-xs-12 col-sm-3'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'></div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene col-xs-12 col-sm-3'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'></div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene col-xs-12 col-sm-3'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'></div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .box-scene {
        -webkit-perspective: 700;
        height: 180px;
        float:left;
        z-index: 999;
        padding:0px !important;
    }
    .box-scene:hover .box {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 90px 90px -90px;
    }
    .face {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    .front {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        z-index: 2;
        background: #d9d9d9;
    }
    .side {
        background: #9dcc78;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

JS

```
var resizer = function () {
        var width = parseInt($(".box-scene").css("width"));
        $(".box").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "center center -" + width / 2 + "px");
    };

    resizer();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizer();
    });
```

Comment: what you want? not clear!

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the panel the other way will fix the mirror imaging of the text.

```
.box-scene:hover .box {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: so the text doesn't end up backwards this way, but you can see the hover effect isn't the same.  This hover rotates the panel to the back.  My feeling is that having -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; on the .face and then pulling it left with left:0px; is the wrong initial set up.  But I'm not sure.